# Python Beautiful Soup Iterate over Multiple Tables

Tags: python, web-scraping, html-table, beautifulsoup

Trying to find multiple tables using the CSS names and I am only getting the CSS in the output initially. I want to loop over each of the small tables and from there each row contains player info with the tds attributes about each player. How come what I have there doesn't actually print the table contents to begin with? I want to confirm I have made this first step right, before I then go on and into
the tr and tds for each mini table. I think part of the issue is that the first table.

My program -

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#url = 'https://www.skysports.com/premier-league-table'
base_url = 'https://www.skysports.com'

# Squad Data
squad_url = base_url + '/liverpool-squad'
squad_r = requests.get(squad_url)

print(squad_r.status_code)

premier_squad_soup = BeautifulSoup(squad_r.text, 'html.parser')

premier_squad_table = premier_squad_soup.find_all = ('table', {'class': 'table -small no-wrap football-squad-table '})
print(premier_squad_table)
```

HTML -

```
    each table looks like the following but with a different title

    <table class="table -small no-wrap football-squad-table " title="Goalkeeper">
                            <colgroup>
                                <col class="" style="">
                                <col class="digit-4 -bp30-hdn">
                                <col class="digit-3 ">
                                <col class="digit-3 ">
                                <col class="digit-3 ">
                            </colgroup>
                            <thead>
                                <tr class="text-s -interact text-h6" style="">
                                    <th class=" text-h4 -txt-left" title="">Goalkeeper</th>
                                    <th class="  text-h6" title="Played">Pld</th>
                                    <th class="  text-h6" title="Goals">G</th>
                                    <th class="  text-h6" title="Yellow Cards ">YC</th>
                                    <th class="  text-h6" title="Red Cards">RC</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                                                        <tr class="text-h6 -center">
                                        <td>
                                              <a href="/football/player/141016/alisson-ramses-becker">
                                            <div class="row-table -2cols">
                                                <span class="col span4/5 -txt-left"><h6 class=" text-h5">Alisson Ramses Becker</h6></span>
                                            </div>
                                              </a>

                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            13 (0)                                            </td>
                                        <td>0</td>
                                        <td>0</td>
                                        <td>0</td>
                                    </tr>
                                                                        <tr class="text-h6 -center">
                                        <td>
                                              <a href="/simon-mignolet">
                                            <div class="row-table -2cols">
                                                <span class="col span4/5 -txt-left"><h6 class=" text-h5">Simon Mignolet</h6></span>
                                            </div>
                                              </a>

                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            1 (0)                                            </td>
                                        <td>0</td>
                                        <td>0</td>
                                        <td>0</td>
                                    </tr>
                                                                        <tr class="text-h6 -center">
                                        <td>
                                              <a href="/football/player/153304/kamil-grabara">
                                            <div class="row-table -2cols">
                                                <span class="col span4/5 -txt-left"><h6 class=" text-h5">Kamil Grabara</h6></span>
                                            </div>
                                              </a>

                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            1 (1)                                            </td>
                                        <td>0</td>
                                        <td>0</td>
                                        <td>0</td>
                                    </tr>
                                                                </tbody>
                        </table>
```

Output - 
        200
    ('table', {'class': 'table -small no-wrap football-squad-table '})

Answer (score 0):

Had to find the div first to then get the table inside the div

premier_squad_div = premier_squad_soup.find('div', {'class': '-bp30-box col span1/1'})
premier_squad_table = premier_squad_div.find_all('table', {'class': 'table -small no-wrap football-squad-table '})